# Unique index not unique in INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Consider the following very simple foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person]([id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, [name] nvarchar(400) NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Order]([id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, [pid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL)
GO

/****** Index: [uindex] ******/
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [uindex] on [Person] ([id])
GO

/****** ForeignKey: [FK_Order_Person] ******/
ALTER TABLE [Order] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Person] FOREIGN KEY([pid])
REFERENCES [Person] ([id])
GO
```

You'll first notice that there is no PK on `[Person]`, only a unique index which allows me to create the foreign key reference to `[Person].[id]`.

`[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS]` shows what I would expect: a row linking the foreign key name `[FK_Order_Person]` with the unique constraint name `[uindex]`.

So my question is: forced to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in SQL Server Compact, where do I get the table and column information for index `[uindex]`?

A join to `[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE]` yields nothing as I don't have a primary key.

In this example I could join to `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[INDEXES]`, but no rule enforces this name to be unique between table or schema's, so if another unique key exists by the same name, then I wouldn't be able to work out where this foreign key points.

Comment: So what you really want is not the index information, since there could be a unique index that you are uninterested in, but rather you want the foreign key constraint and what field it references.

Comment: Correct. I'm after the foreign key information, FK (table,column[s]) along with referenced(table,column[s]).

Answer (score 0):

```
                "SELECT KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS FK_TABLE_NAME,  KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME, KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_COLUMN_NAME, " +
            "KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS UQ_TABLE_NAME, KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS UQ_CONSTRAINT_NAME, KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS UQ_COLUMN_NAME, RC.UPDATE_RULE, RC.DELETE_RULE, KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION AS UQ_ORDINAL_POSITION, KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AS FK_ORDINAL_POSITION " +
            "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC " +
            "JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1 ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME " +
            "JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 ON  KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME =  RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AND KCU2.TABLE_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_TABLE_NAME " +
            "WHERE KCU1.TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "' " +
            "ORDER BY FK_TABLE_NAME, FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME, FK_ORDINAL_POSITION"
```

And then they need to be grouped, see my scripting API for details,

Comment: Cannot inner join to KCU2, because UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME is the name of the index, which does not exist in KCU, as its not a key.

Answer (score 0):

There's a false assumption in this statement:
"In this example I could join to [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[INDEXES], but no rule enforces this name to be unique between table or schema's, so if another unique key exists by the same name, then I wouldn't be able to work out where this foreign key points."

In Sql Compact there is only one schema, so the table-name and index-name combination are unique.
In addition, the view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS does contain the name of the unique constraint table as well as the unique constraint name. (This is different to the equivalent Sql Server view)

Note, however, that the INDEXES view actually contains one row per index column (there is no index definition view) but this means you can then correlate the foreign key columns and unique index columns.